# How to structure project with Spring Boot, Gradle, and JSPs

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I started studying Spring by using a book, but I'm stuck in a point. I'm implementing the example of the book and since I want to run the app, I'm using spring-boot. The only thing I get is a 
"There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available".

I'm using a ServletDispatcher configured as this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpittrWebAppInitializer.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the WebConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spitter.web")

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    } 
}
```

This is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }


}
```

And this is the structure of the project I'm using:

```
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   └── spittr
│   │   │       ├── config
│   │   │       │   ├── RootConfig.class
│   │   │       │   ├── SpittrWebAppInitializer.class
│   │   │       │   └── WebConfig.class
│   │   │       └── web
│   │   │           └── HomeController.class
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── spittr
│   │           └── web
│   │               └── HomeControllerTest.class
│   └── resources
│       └── main
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── spittr
    │   │       ├── config
    │   │       │   ├── RootConfig.java
    │   │       │   ├── SpittrWebAppInitializer.java
    │   │       │   └── WebConfig.java
    │   │       └── web
    │   │           └── HomeController.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── spittr
        │       └── web
        │           └── HomeControllerTest.java
        └── resources
```

Now if I make a request to localhost:8080 I get the 404 error, probably because I have to put the jsp views in a folder reachable by the ViewResolver.

Where, exactly in the tree I pasted, the WEB-INF/views/ folder must be put? 
Is it the place where the jsp must be inserted?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JSPs with Spring Boot, you'll have to use the WAR format instead of the fat JAR format.

Consult the section on [JSP Limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) in the Spring Boot reference manual as well as the [Spring Boot JSP Sample Application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp). That example uses Maven, but if you follow the guidelines in the Spring Boot reference manual, you will be able to achieve the same result with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

judging by your folder structure and the `ViewResolver` prefix definition you'll have to create under your `main` directory the following directories and add your `jsp` files there:

```
main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I guess it is for the limitations that Sam Brannen wrote above. Thanks anyway!